# Advantage of boost::bimap::unordered_set_of v/s std::unordered_set

Tags: boost-bimap

I'm using a bidirectional map to link a list of names to a particular single name (for example, to correlate cities and countries). So, my definition of the type is something like:

```
using boost::bimap<boost::bimaps::unordered_set_of<std::string>, std::string> CitiesVsCountries;
```

But one question intrigues me:

What's the advantage on using a `boost::bimaps::unordered_set_of<std::string>` v/s a simple `std::unordered_set`? The advantage of the bimap is clear (avoing having to synchronize by hand two maps), but I can't really see what added value is giving the Boost version of the unordered set, nor I can find any document detailing the difference.

Thanks a lot for your help.